# How can I hightlight text with pdfkit pdfview

Tags: ios, swift, pdfview, ios-pdfkit

I use pdfkit and I want to customize the menu contents of the selected text that appears. When I long-press and select the text, the system menu pops up with the highlight option, and nothing happens when I click on highlight.
I want to customize the menu and replace the highlight copy and other options on the current system.

My code implementation:

```
class MyPDFVC: UIViewController, PDFViewDelegate {

let pdfView = PDFView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    pdfView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
    self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    pdfView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pdfView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
    
    //加载的 PDF 文件
    if let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SPR-pdf", withExtension: "pdf"), let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL) {

        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        pdfView.goToFirstPage(nil)
    }
}
```

}

The imageShot is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaMTn.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight selected text in pdf using PDFKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860727/how-to-highlight-selected-text-in-pdf-using-pdfkit)

Comment: thanks.  I do not want to highlight the text, is it the previous step operation, because I have not yet got the selected text.
I want to long-press the selected text and bring up the highlight menu for this part of the ui. For example, in the screenshot uploaded in the question, after I long press, the system will select the text and display the highlight menu, but I did not have any effect when I clicked, and I could not capture the click event to add the highlighted code you sent. I want to capture the click event or delete the highlight menu, or disable the system longpress selected text

Comment: Try changing the highlight background colour of the text selection. Also, would be easier if you could share a minimal reproducible sample of your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: than you. I have edit my ask, and add my code, please help me check it.   Simple to say. I want to customize the menu contents of the selected text that appears.  My phone is IOS 16.0.